# JSP EL not working - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: jsp, el

I have a problem with JSP EL that i figure it out.
In my Servlet doGet() method i'm using this code to retrieve data from data base :

```
    UserServices us = new UserServices();
    List<User> users= us.allUsers();
    request.setAttribute("users", users);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/list_users.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The Problem is when i use JSP Scriplets & Expressions like this :

```
<%
List<User> users = (List<User>) request.getAttribute("users");
if(users != null) {
    for(User user : users) {
%>
        <p><%=user.getName()%></p>
<%
    }
}
%>
```

It works fine but when i use JSP EL :

```
<p>${user.name}</p>
```

this error prompt out :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String
```

**EDIT :**
My user class :

```
class User {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Can you paste your `User` class?

Comment: I added my User class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried similar code. Just add `public` keyword in your `User` class like below:

```
public class User {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String age;

   //Geters & Setters
}
```

Add `isELIgnored="false"` in `<%@ page %>` directive.